# C# Implicit operators and ToString()

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

I'm creating my own type for representing css values (like pixels eg. 12px ). To be able to add/subtract/multiply/... my type and ints I've defined two implicit operators to and from int. Everything works great except one thing.. If I write:

```
CssUnitBase c1 = 10;
Console.WriteLine(c1);
```

I get "10" instead of "10px" - implicit conversion to int is used instead ToString() method. How can I prevent that?

Comment: Can you post the code to the `CssUnitBase` class? From the way you use it it appears to _be_ a wrapper around int.

Comment: ut dipends on how you store internally the value in CssUnitBase and how you return it. "Talk is cheap, show us the code"

Comment: @vaitrafra: I don't see how it depends on that at all. There's an implicit conversion to/from int, and an override for ToString. Those are the bits of the public API which are relevant in this question, and I don't think their implementation matters at all. It's what gets called which is relevant.

Comment: What matters is which overload of WriteLine the compiler chooses. It chooses int because there is a valid conversion. ToString is called by WriteLine internally, so it has no bearing on which overload is chosen by the compiler.

Comment: you're gonna have to do something explicit to force WriteLine to actually show you the output of your ToString method because if you add an operator to convert to string, then the call will be ambiguous between both overloads and you have to do an explicit cast or explicit call to ToString anyway. Screenshot to demonstrate what I'm talking about: https://puu.sh/EeIos/4957898796.png so you should probably just say `Console.WriteLine(c1.ToString());`

Answer (score 15):

Yes, there's an implicit conversion to `int` and the overload of `WriteLine(int)` is more specific than `WriteLine(object)`, so it'll use that.

You could *explicitly* call the `WriteLine(object)` overload:

```
Console.WriteLine((object)c1);
```

... or you could call `ToString` yourself, so that `Console.WriteLine(string)` is called:

```
Console.WriteLine(c1.ToString());
```

... or you could just remove the implicit conversion to `int`. Just how useful is it to you? I'm generally not in favour of implicit conversions for this sort of thing... (You could keep the implicit conversion *from* `int` of course, if you really wanted to.)

Comment: I've done that quite another way. Implicit conversion to int is now explicit and I have 4 operators (+-*/) overloaded that operate on CssUnitBase. This way I have both - ToString is called by default and arithmetic operations are working well(on mixture of int and CssUnitBase operands) without much code. All operations like CssUnitBase * int should always return CssUnitBase so this is in every aspect the way I want it.

Comment: @kubal5003: That sounds like the right way of doing things, yes. Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 1):

Override the "ToString()" method and use c1.ToString().

Answer (score 1):

Just override the `ToString` method in `CssUnitBase` and call that when you want it as a string.